# Django ORM Arithmetic operation with columns from different subqueries

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm

I have a table:

```
test_id   url      value
1        'url1'      3
1        'url2'      3
1        'url3'      7
2        'url1'      5
2        'url2'      4
2        'url3'      2
```

In django I have a function with 2 incoming variables for different test_id`s:

```
def tests_compare_aggregate(request, test_id_1, test_id_2):
```

I need to execute SQL-query, which will show the difference between urls values for these 2 test_id`s, like:

```
SELECT t1.url, t1.value - t2.value FROM 
(SELECT url, value FROM table WHERE test_id = test_id_1) t1,
(SELECT url, value FROM table WHERE test_id = test_id_2) t2 WHERE
t1.url = t2.url
```

So I have two QuerySet`s:

```
t1 = Table.objects.filter(test_id=test_id_1).values('test_id,'url','value')
t2 = Table.objects.filter(test_id=test_id_2).values('test_id,'url','value')
```

What to do with them next or is there any another way? I tryed a lot of things, but nothing worked.

Comment: You want to do a basic subtraction between values of t1 and t2? Am I reading your question right?

Comment: yep, but for every url